# How to integrate Parse.com with Superfeedr

Tags: parse-platform, superfeedr

I want to integrate Parse.com with Superfeedr website.
I am building RSS reader where I want Superfeedr to notify Parse.com when there is a new RSS FEED. it a PUSH mechanism instead of traditional way to pull RSS feeds every specified period of time.

the issue I face is: Superfeedr needs a callback url to send a post request to it when there is a new RSS feed.

I dont know how to provide callback url from Parse.com cloud. How to do so ?

Comment: Julien fro [Superfeedr](https://superfeedr.com) here. I think we'll indeed need someone from Parse to answer the question as we need to know if they're able to provide URLs to your application.

Comment: You may want to look at this [blog post](http://blog.parse.com/announcements/introducing-cloud-code-webhooks/).